# Blog Archive ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm using ASP.NET MVC3. Currently I have a blog. Its working well but the entries are now getting many so I need a archieve to group them monthly. The problem is I dont have an idea how to do it.. 
I'm thinking its on the datetime but I don't know the logic behind it.. I want to achieve something like this

```
September 2012 (1)
October 2012 (3)
December 2012 (0)
```

I would appreciate anyone who would help me. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it like this. I have the same problem before.
**ArchiveRepository**

```
 public IQueryable<ArchiveListModel> AchiveList()
        {

            var ac = from Post in db.Posts
                     group Post by new { Post.DateTime.Year
, Post.DateTime.Month }
                     into dategroup
                     select new ArchiveListModel()
                      {

                         AchiveYear = dategroup.Key.Year,
                         AchiveMonth = dategroup.Key.Month,
                         PostCount = dategroup.Count()

                       };

            return ac;
        }
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult ArchiveBrowse(int AchiveYear, int AchiveMonth, int PostCount)
        {
            var archivemodel = (from a in db.Posts
                                where a.DateTime.Year == AchiveYear &&
                                      a.DateTime.Month == AchiveMonth
                                select a).ToList();


            return View(archivemodel);
        }
```

**View**

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
@Html.ActionLink(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(item.AchiveMonth) + "" + item.AchiveYear + " (" + item.PostCount + ")",
  "ArchiveBrowse", "Post", new
  {
      AchiveYear = item.AchiveYear,
      AchiveMonth = item.AchiveMonth,
      PostCount = item.PostCount
  }, null) 

}
```

Comment: Thanks. It's been a month ago after I asked this question. But still this helps.